# Wrong page title in unanswered list questions page

Tags: bug, status-completed, unanswered-questions, window-title, custom-filters

*(first [discovered](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/386897/wrong-page-title-in-unanswered-list-questions-page) on SO)*

There seems to be a problem with title management on SE sites:

In fact, the title displayed when visiting the [Unanswered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions?tab=Unanswered) page on a SE site is "*Highest Votes Questions*", instead of "*Unanswered Questions*". The problem is also here for the *[Unanswered (my tags)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged?tab=Unanswered&tagMode=Watched)* and *Unanswered with custom tag* ([ex on SO with "*css*"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css?tab=Unanswered)) pages.

[image: Wrong title of "unanswered questions" list page example]

---

If you visit any other "filter" page there is no problem; i.e. the correct title is displayed.

Comment: Pretty sure it's a side-effect of the custom filters, adding the tag so the dev who did it will take a look.

Answer (score 2):

This is fixed.

That title was coming from the fact that the unanswered tab is sorted by votes.  The logic has been revised to base things off the tab, if a tab is active, and otherwise say that it's a custom filtered list.

Comment: Great! Thanks for providing such a great platform and keeping it updated :)