# Change title for Retracted flags in the Flag History page

Tags: feature-request, wording, flag-history, window-title

Currently, when choosing to [view retracted flags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/flag-summary/current?group=3&status=6), the title of the page becomes something like this:

> [image: Image of title which reads "Retracted Rude/Abusive flags raised by [name]" on flag history page]

Or in words: (bold emphasis mine)

> **Retracted** Rude/Abusive flags **raised** by [my name here]

I don't think "Retracted" and "raised" can go together like that. The title should be just "Retracted Rude/Abusive flags by..." or "Rude/Abusive flags retracted by...", in my opinion.

Comment: maybe related to this fix: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/332008/158100 ?

Comment: @rene don't think so, it's not a new behavior, I just never bothered to ask changing it. :-)

Comment: The flags were raised. Retracting them doesn't change that.

Comment: @Catija but for me it reads as "raised a new flag, of type retracted".

Comment: It's English... we can't fix it completely. I do assure you, it means what it should. I'm not sure where you're seeing this, though? Screenshot?

Comment: @Catija sure, added.

Comment: If you remove "raised" it is no longer clear that it are your own flags you retracted. It could then be anyones flag. I think it's fine as is.

Comment: @Luuklag there's still the "by" part, and even a mod can't retract a flag cast by users, at least not in the way the user can.

Comment: the by part would then reference the retraction solely, not the ownership of the flag. Which could lead to confusion.

Comment: Making it more verbose could make it clearer, such as "Rude/Abusive flags raised by [my name here] which have been retracted". While the primary interpretation of the original wording means what's intended, it could be misinterpreted as described in the question. Interpreting it correctly is easier with the supplemental information that it's not possible to raise a retracted flag, but that's available from the fuller context. Perhaps the issue is that it's not as understandable to those who are not as proficient in English? In some cases, a bit more verbosity helps to make the meaning clearer.

Answer (score 5):

The root title is `Rude/Abusive flags raised by foobar`. The [Helpful / Declined / Retracted] text in the respective subdivision is simply appended to the beginning of the root title.

So the titles should be read as such:

- [Helpful] [Rude/Abusive flags raised by foobar]
- [Declined] [Rude/Abusive flags raised by foobar]
- [Retracted] [Rude/Abusive flags raised by foobar]

But *not* as such:

- [Helpful Rude/Abusive flags] [raised by foobar]
- [Declined Rude/Abusive flags] [raised by foobar]
- [Retracted Rude/Abusive flags] [raised by foobar]

So in the case of retracted flags, the title is *not* referring to the *retracted flags* that have been *raised*, rather, it's referring to the *raised flags* that have been *retracted*.

Hence, the current wording conveys what it is meant to convey, although it could be made a bit clearer to avoid said confusion.